# Pythonw seg faults when using wxpython on Mac

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, anaconda

I am trying to run a GUI that first queries the user for an input file (using wxpython) and then processes data from that file to display on a graph (using pyside and matplotlib). I am running this within an Anaconda environment. This entire setup works fine on a PC, but when I transfer it to a Mac, I start getting errors.

Note: I am fairly sure that the issue is with wxpython, as I tried running the program with the input file given as a command-line arg instead of having the wxpython input text box pop up. This worked perfectly fine (graph displayed and did not close or have any other errors).

**When I run the program with python, I get an error immediately:**

```
$ python graph_app_main.py 
This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac.
```

I looked for similar issues people had with wxpython porting to Mac - a couple of places ([ex.](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/607)) suggested using pythonw instead of python, but then I get a seg fault. The set fault did not seem to happen to anyone else who switched to using pythonw.

**When I run the program with pythonw,** it shows me the input text box, lets me enter the input file name, and then even displays the graph. However, after about a second, the graph disappears and I get an error message from the Mac "python quit unexpectedly".

```
$ pythonw graph_app_main.py 
/Users/rwicks/anaconda/envs/PIXL/bin/pythonw: line 3:   943 Segmentation fault: 11  /Users/rwicks/anaconda/envs/PIXL/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"`
```

**Here is the Mac's error log (too much text to fit into main body, so I linked it)**
http://textuploader.com/xhzi

I'm really at a loss, as no one's seemed to have similar issues. I might have to switch to a different module that also has input boxes but is more portable.

EDIT: Here are all my imports

```
# graph_app_main - creates a GraphApp class and 
# calls methods from the Data Parser to get data file from user,
# parse the data, and finally pass that data into the GraphApp
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os.path   
from graph_app import GraphApp 
from data_parser import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
```

And

```
#GraphApp Class
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PySide'
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
```

And

```
#Data Parser where I have the wx input box ask for a data file
from __future__ import print_function
import wx
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Continuum's python distribution, but I find it odd that there are QtGui module and libQt calls in the call stack for the thread that crashed.  Something smells a little fishy there.

Comment: @RobinDunn I think my imports are all PySide's versions of those, I added the blocks of code where I imported anything to the end of the original post

Comment: @rwicks you are aware that PySide (a wrapper for QT) and wxPython (a wrapper for wxWidgets) are two different UI tools.  Your line "matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4']='PySide'" indicates that you use the PySide backend, if you want to use the wxPython backend you would set this to WXAgg, but then you also need to remove all the PySide imports.  Maybe you show your complete script.